# String hex hash to bytes

Tags: java, arrays, hash

I have String *hash* in hex form ("e6fb06210fafc02fd7479ddbed2d042cc3a5155e") and I would like to compare it to crypt.digest().
One way, which works fine, is to convert crypt.digest() to hex, but I would like to avoid multiple conversions and rather convert hash from hex form (above) to byte array.

What I tried was:

```
byte[] hashBytes = new BigInteger(hash, 16).toByteArray();
```

but it does not match with crypt.digest(). When I convert hashBytes back to hex I get "**00**e6fb06210fafc02fd7479ddbed2d042cc3a5155e".

The leading zeros seem to be the reason why I fail to match byte arrays. Why do they occur? How can I get the same result using crypt.digest() and toByteArray?

Comment: Note that there is this idiomatic thread about the duplicate topic: [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java). Just in case you need a solution and do not want to wait for a fix of your approach.

Comment: See the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140592/2411243) in the linked thread, comment section. It explains it.

Comment: Thank you for both quick answers! It helped me to understand the reason and find solution (although I saw the thread when I looked for the solution).

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140592/2411243) from a thread about the highly related question [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java):

> The issue with `BigInteger` is that there must be a **"sign bit"**. If the leading byte has the high bit set then the resulting byte array has an **extra 0** in the 1st position. But still +1.
>
> – Gray Oct 28 '11 at 16:20

Since the first bit has a special meaning (indicating the sign, 0 for positive, 1 for negative), `BigInteger` will prefix the data with an additional `0` in case your data started with a `1` on the high bit. Otherwise it would be interpreted as negative although it was not negative to begin with.

I.e. data like

```
101110
```

is turned into

```
0101110
```

You could easily *undo* this manually by using `Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 1, data.length)` if it happens.

---

However, instead of fixing that code, I would suggest using one of the other solutions posted in the linked thread. They are cleaner and easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the extra 00 is that `e6` has it high (sign) bit set.
A redundant byte 00 makes it an unsigned value for BigInteger.

```
    String hash = "e6fb06210fafc02fd7479ddbed2d042cc3a5155e";
    byte[] hashBytes = new BigInteger(hash, 16).toByteArray();
    hashBytes = hashBytes.length > 1 && hashBytes[0] == 0
        ? Arrays.copyOfRange(hashBytes, 1, hashBytes.length) : hashBytes;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashBytes));
```

The question arises, what if the hash actually starts with a 00?
Then you need the hash length, or do a lenient comparison.